# Apple Time Capsule will not start -up, light stays amber

Tags: time-machine

I unplugged my Time Capsule today to tidy up the wires. After plugging back in it refuses to start.

1. Have tried resetting by sticking pencil in the back
2. Tried leaving, it's been stuck in Amber for 3 hours now

I believe it's third generation, that's about it.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with mine (with the strange noise repeating every 1/3 of a second), however after a lot of restarts and resets it didn't come back. Sad but true... running out of ideas...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it appear at all in your list of wifi access points on any of your devices? If so, try to connect to it and see if there's anything mentioned in the Air Port Utility app.

If it doesn't, I managed to find **[this discussion on the Apple Discussions forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4060327?start=0&tstart=0)** regarding Time Capsules being stuck on the amber light at startup. The possible problems suggested by those forum-goers include:

- Failing power supply
- Failing HDD

If your Time Capsule is within warranty, it'd be worth it to take it in and have them look at it. Unless it's a failing HDD, however, it's not looking like there's a lot in the way of DIY repairs for the device.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I fear it's one of those two. Failing HDD I guess. Time for a new one.

Comment: You're very welcome. I hope that everything works out; and nothing like a new device to bring a smile to a techie's face. Hope everything works out!

Comment: Good news, it just started working again after a reboot. Seems very temperamental if you simply switch off at the wall. Still going to treat myself to a new one though :-)

Comment: @MichaelGill I just had exactly the same problem with my Time Capsule, and after a few restarts it begins working normally. Could you let me know how yours is now? I suspect it was a failing HDD because I heard a strange drive head noise repeating every 1/3 of a second.

Comment: BTW mine was purchased in Oct 2009.